# Different methods for the probability of choosing students for a committee

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

For this question, what I did was:

$\frac2{18} \times \frac 1{17} \times \frac2{12} \times \frac1{11}$

The first two fractions are related to the choosing of girls and the next two are related to the choosing of boys.

However, my answer was extremely small= $9.90 \times 10 E -5 $. And the answer is indeed different from mine, as they did it in this way: 
[image]

Can someone tell me what is the difference between the two ways of doing it and why the answer calculated from both ways are different?

Many thanks and sorry in advance for any wrong tags and title labelling.

Comment: Your process is totally wrong whereas your book has the exact answer and correct process.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, would it be possible if you can guide me in where I went wrong?

Comment: I mean your process is just wrong. Not that you started good and then made a conceptual mistake. It was just that it is not the right process. You just did something totally wrong. Still if you want any clarification, you have perhaps made some mistake in choosing the total no of cases. You have missed the cases where the committee has 3B,1G and such other cases.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, I am not quite sure whether your comment about the case for the committee being 3B and 1G is correct. The question specifically asks for 2G, 2B.

Comment: The $^{30}C_4$ in the denominator includes the $3G,1B$ case and similar cases. Any doubts regarding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's answer is like this:

```
Choose 2 boys in one of C(12 2) ways.
Choose 2 girls in one of C(18 2) ways.
Total ways to choose 2 B, 2 G = the product of those two.

For the probability of choosing 2 B, 2 G, 
divide that result by total ways to choose 4 students: C(30 4).
```

Another way is this:

```
P(choose girl) = 18/30 *
P(choose girl) = 17/29 *
P(choose boy) = 12/28 *
P(choose boy) = 11/27 *
Number of ways to order 2 B and 2 G in a group of 4 = C(4 2) = 6
```

What you calculated was

```
P(first person chosen is a girl, and either Alice or Betty) and
P(next person chosen is a girl, and the other of those two) and
P(next person chosen is a boy, and either Carl or Dave) and
P(next person chosen is a boy, and the other of those two).
```

Answer (score 1):

@CCC, you are calculating something like the probability that Girls G1 and G2 are selected in random order, etc. Where as the order in which girls and boys are selected is fixed. This obviously completely different from a random order of boys/girl, and random girls/boys within the set.

Comment: do you mean that my answer is calculating the situation where the choosing of the girl is fixed, whereas the answer is random?@Pieter21

Comment: Yes. Also if you started instead of 2/18 with 18/30, it would also come closer to the correct solution (need drawing reorder factor)